# Closure of $f\mapsto\sigma f''$ on $\mathcal{C}^2(\,[0,1]\,)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Let $\sigma\in\mathcal{C}^0(]0,1])$ a positive function such that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}\sigma(t)=0$, and $f\in\mathcal{C}^0(\,[0,1]\,)\cap\mathcal{C}^2(\,]0,1]\,)$ such that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \sigma f''(t)=0$.

**Question:** Does there exist a sequence $(f_n)\in\mathcal{C}^2(\,[0,1]\,)$ such that, in the sense of the uniform norm on $\mathcal{C}^0(\,[0,1]\,)$

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f $$
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sigma f''_n = \sigma f'' $$

Comment: Did you already answer that question with one less derivative?

Comment: No, but I agree that treating first the same question replacing $\mathcal{C}^2$ by $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $f'',f_n''$ by $f',f_n'$ is natural.